# No show weights option available?

Tags: weight-painting

It doesn't appear to be available in adds ons either.. I know I've checked it off before, so I'm confused where it went.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You must be in edit mode, with a mesh selected.

Comment: And it is under Mesh Display.